# Tailwind randomly decides to disable styles NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a pretty common problem with my NextJs production build. Although, it occasionally happens in development too, my main concern is that sometimes when I deploy my project some of the styles just don't work as if classNames aren't even there.

For example:

```
<div className='space-x-4'>
  <span />
  <span />
  <span />
</div>
```

I would expect my spans to have 1rem of space between them and it works fine in development but once deployed all of the spans are stuck together with no margins. (The only workaround for this is to switch around tailwind imports in global.scss and redeploy) - after testing I've come to conclusion that this statement is false and simple redeploy helps however the question is still open.

Example:

**Doesn't work**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**Works**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind components;
```

**Works**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Similar questions have already been raised/answered however none of them seem to be helpful in my case. I tried different imports and checked my tailwind config countless times. What's weird is that **it doesn't happen every deploy** just now and then but still very annoying.

I'd be very grateful for any advices or insights on why this is happening.

configs:

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    'src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    'src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    ...
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
};
```

postcss.config.js (just exists)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Comment: could you please provide a repo or at least your tailwind, postcss and next config?

Comment: I have uploaded configs you can check them out.

Comment: Some ideas i would check:   
1. make sure that production mode is on during build
2. change  src/pages and src/components to ./src/pagens and ./src/components
or try to disable purge at all
3. try to disable jit mode

Comment: I shall check but I'm pretty sure it's on. Also, I don't think it has to do with purging since it doesn't happen every time. Jit might be the reason but I want to try and fix it, disabling it would be too much pain unfortunately

Comment: could you let me know your `package.json` ?